# Share variable between methods in Java

Tags: java, variables, methods

I'm new in Java and I have little problem. I want to make array in one method and display in length in other. I know how to to both in one method:

```
class Test
{
    public void create()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Number of elements: ");
        int n=in.nextInt();
        int arr[]=new int[n];
        System.out.println("Number of elements: " + arr.length);
    }
}
```

But how can I do something like this?

```
class Test
{
    public void create()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Number of elements: ");
        int n=in.nextInt();
        int arr[]=new int[n];
    }

    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Wielkosc tablicy: " + arr.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make `arr` a private instance variable of class `Test`.

Answer (score 1):

Make `arr` a private instance variable of your class, so that it is accessible from any method:

```
class Test
{
    private int[] arr;
    public void create()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Number of elements: ");
        int n=in.nextInt();
        arr=new int[n];
    }

    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Wielkosc tablicy: " + arr.length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is only expected to exist within the lifetime of a call to `create` I'd recommend making `display` private. Then updating the signature of display to take an int[] as an argument

```
class Test {
    public void create() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Number of elements: ");
        int n=in.nextInt();
        int arr[]=new int[n];
        display(arr);
    }

    private void display(int[] arr) {
        System.out.println("Wielkosc tablicy: " + arr.length);
    }
}
```

If the int[] is to live for longer than just the call to `create` then you should make the int[] a field on on `Test` as mentioned in the answer by @lodo

Comment: Given that method `display` is public, while `arr` is calculated inside the class, this does not seem 100% right. Maybe the user of class `Test` wants to display info about the class, but expects the array to be given by `create`, and so needs to call `display` without any parameter.

Comment: Given the nature of the question I don't think that the subtlety of reasoning you have used is necessarily applicable!

Comment: Not necessarily, but possibily. But you are right, this is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: I've updated my answer some to hopefully account for the ambiguity of the situation